# Modelling enzyme reaction kinetics in R

Tags: r, regression

I have a simple data set with three experiments, three replicates each, measurements of enzyme activity performed at concentrations of an enzyme of 0, 1, 10 and 100. Is there a standard way, transformation to apply to the data, package or regression variant of modelling the reaction kinetics?

EDIT: we are only interested to know that there is a significant dependence of the read-out on the enzyme concentration, not in calculate the specific parameters.

Comment: With what type of kinetics do you wish to model this reaction?

Comment: Also, you have very few data points. Then you need to be really sure that your model of the reaction kinetics is correct. It is not difficult to get a proper fit trough three points, so there will not be any way to verify whether your model is reasonable. This is fine of course when the method/model is already established to be correct/useful and you just wish to estimate model parameters.

Comment: Also, for particular models of kinetics it might be better to have three single points at a spread of concentrations rather than three at the same concentration (for instance use concentrations 1, 2, 4, 10, 20, 40, 100, 200, 400 instead of 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100). It allows to 1: control for systematic errors 2: if there is some shift in activity at a specific spot e.g. $K_m$ in Michaelis-Menten kinetics, you may more optimally estimate it (I say this intuitively, I would actually have to verify it).

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I completely agree regarding the choice of replicates; unfortunately, I did not design this experiment.

Comment: What dou you mean by 'read-out'? Also, most often the enzyme concentration dependency is linear with reaction 
rate (independent from the type of kinetics), but maybe this is not the same as your 'read-out'.  So it should not be such a difficult problem. It seems like you have a much more specific problem than the very general question. The general question can only be answered in general terms (the answer is: "there is no standard way"). More details, specifications, and explanations will improve the detail in the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You do not transform the data.

This used to be done in the pre-computer era when computations where difficult (see for instance the determination of constants in Michaelis-Menten kinetics where the observations used to be plotted with a linearising transformation https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanes-Woolf_plot ).

Nowadays the (non linear) equations that describe the kinetics are fitted directly to the observations by using one of many non linear regression techniques.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree, but could you be more specific? What approaches, what packages, what types of models are used?

Comment: The statistic model to be used is determined by the physical model. E.g. when you are dealing with Michaelis-Menten kinetics then the formula is of the form $y = \frac{a x}{b+x}$. Depending on how precise and exact you want to be you could do some approach with more advanced determination of error propagation. But, I guess that most people just use a simple and regular non-linear least squares regression and use the associated confidence intervals (E. g. assuming iid normal  errors). This can be done in R with a function `nls` which is part of the `stats` package, which is a core package in R.